# Why does pip not install tensorflow version below 2.12?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I'm currently following the tensorflow guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native_1.
Up until step 6, everything works, however I cannot install the proper tensorflow version.
Only the version 2.12 can be installed.

When testing if it is installed for my GPU with

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

it shows me an empty list, so it probably doesn't work.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix this?

Comment: What version of Python are you using, and does your target release of tensorflow support that version?

Comment: What happens if you use "pip install "tensorflow<2.11""  ?
For the GPU part you better look up some longer documentations on how to do that after youve eventually installed the correct version of tensorflow

Comment: @Brian61354270 I'm currently using python 3.9 for that

Answer (score 1):

`Tensorflow 2.12` is not supported for GPU setup in Windows OS.

> TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on
> native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to
> install TensorFlow in WSL2, or install tensorflow-cpu and, optionally,
> try the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin

Please try after installing tensorflow 2.10 and following all the **Hardware/Software requirements** mentioned in the same link to enable GPU support in your system.

```
pip install tensorflow==2.10
```

Let us know if the issue still persists.

Comment: Why did they remove support from Windows?

Comment: That gets a pip error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.10`

Answer (score 0):

Only Tensorflow up to 2.10 is supported for GPU setup in Windows OS.
Unfortunately, You cannot install it using `pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.10` as you will receive

> *Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement*

You should install it from a wheel file at pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/2.10.0/#files.
One way to do it is to download the appropriate (same python version, same OS ...) .whl file locally, then

```
(venv) >> pip install <filename>.whl
```