# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.saved_model.registration' has no attribute 'register_tf_serializable'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conda

I am using conda.
When I ran this code, I got this error.
I am struggling with it for two days,
I tried to update Keras, conda and TensorFlow, but it did not work.
**Keras and tensorflow version 2.11.0**
Here is the code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense , Flatten,Embedding,Input,CuDNNLSTM,LSTM
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence
```

here is the error I got:

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.saved_model.registration' has no attribute 'register_tf_serializable'

Thanks in advance

I tried to update Keras, conda and TensorFlow, but it did not work.

Comment: Please include the full error including traceback information in your question, and also include more of the relevant code around where the error occurs.

Comment: I am trying to import these packages.

Comment: import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense , Flatten ,Embedding,Input,CuDNNLSTM,LSTM
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the error

Comment: Don't use screenshots.  Please copy and paste the error and the relevant code into your question, as it makes that information searchable for future users, and helps others to recreate your issue so we can help.  See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The only reference I can find anywhere to `tensorflow.python.saved_model.registration.register_tf_serializable` is from [this link](https://fossies.org/linux/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/saved_model/registration/README.md), which indicates its from a README.md of `tensorflow 2.12.0`.  The only similar reference in the TensorFlow documentation is [tf.keras.saving.register_keras_serializable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/saving/register_keras_serializable)

Comment: I tried to upgrade the tensoflow version to 2.12.0 but it fails ..

Comment: If you're working in Windows, Tensorflow 2.12 doesn't support using the GPU in windows anymore.  You either have to install Python and Tensorflow into WSL2, or use Tensorflow-cpu.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75654711/why-does-pip-not-install-tensorflow-version-below-2-12

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `.python` while importing above libraries. Also the [tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/text_to_word_sequence) api is deprected to use now and you can use `tf.strings.regex_replace` and `tf.strings.split` which provide equivalent functionality. `cuDNNLSTM` API was used in Tensorflow 1.x which is replaced with `LSTM` in Tensorflow 2.x.

You can import these libraries as below:

```
#from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense , Flatten,Embedding,Input,LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
#from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence #Deprecataed
```

Please verify that you are installing the right tensorflow version with compatible python version as mentioned in this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu). Also make sure you are not using tensorflow 2.11 for GPU support in windows OS because

> GPU support on native-Windows is only available for 2.10 or earlier
> versions. Starting in TF 2.11, CUDA build is not supported for
> Windows. For using TensorFlow GPU on Windows, you will need to
> build/install TensorFlow in WSL2 or use tensorflow-cpu with
> TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin